# get array of Timestamp from Firestore in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get an array of Timestamp from Firestore and store it in a List of DateTime in flutter,
How can I do that?

my Firestore data:
[image]

I want to get these values and print them as DateTime type in Flutter

my code:

```
return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('medicine')
    return StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('medicine')
    .where('userId', isEqualTo: watcherId)
    .snapshots(),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
if (snapshot.data == null) {
return Center(
child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
);
}
final doc = snapshot.data.docs;

return SizedBox(
height: 400.0,
child: ListView.builder(
itemCount: doc.length,
    itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
    final docId = doc[index]['docId'];


//below I tried these but it didn't work
    // List dayOfMonth= List.from(doc[index]['selectedDates']);
    //Timestamp stamp = doc[index]['selectedDates'][index];
    //List<Timestamp> stamp = doc[index]['selectedDates'];
        return;
      }));
    
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the dates out of your data:

```dart
final dates = data[selectedDates]; // this should be a List<TimeStamp>
```

then convert them:

```dart
// ... make sure to check that dates is not null before mapping them
final convertedDates = dates.map((date) => date.toDate()).toList();
```

if you want the dates as a string, then just use `date.toDate().toString()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can display the timestamp as date by using the firestore TimeStamp class

```
Timestamp stamp = _data['selectedDates'][index];
DateTime date = stamp.toDate();
```

you can format the date by:

```
DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(date); //returns a string
```

Comment: this error appeared (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Timestamp')

Comment: try ```_data['selectedDates'][index]```